# How to use memcached with Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, memcached

How can I use memcache in Joomla?  I'm a newbie in this field so please be descriptive with your answer.

Comment: Do you *need* memcached?

Comment: IMHo sites that are using memcached usually should stay away from Joomla or any boxed CMS for that reason. the reason would be - to implement memcached -  you would have to change source php code (perhaps drastically sometimes). Joomla (or any other boxed CMS) have been designed for folks who'd rather design a template instead of changing source code. Also -  you really should not change Joomla's core php as it 'll be rather a hack and you would have problems updating in the future which will make your site VERY easy to hack. Use memchached only if you have a cluster.

Comment: @Andre Joomla's core has a caching layer that implements memcached, XCache, and flat file caches among others. The Joomla Framework has a caching class where you send in a key-value pair, then it handles the caching depending on which driver has been selected in the configuration. There is absolutely no need to hack Joomla to add memcached; it's already built in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to install memcached on your server and will probably need root access to do so.  You can get memcached from http://www.danga.com/memcached/. It requires libevent, which can be downloaded here: http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

Finally, you'll need to get the PHP PECL extension for memcache. To install this, you need to go to the server where PHP is installed and run this command:

```
pecl install memcache
```

Again, you will most likely need root access to your server to do this. After you have libevent, memcached, and the PECL extensions installed, go to the Global Configuration in Joomla and choose `Memory Cache` as the Cache Handler under Cache Settings. After you save the Global Configuration, open it again and more inputs should appear underneath the Cache Handler input. Set Memory Chache Server to `localhost` and the port to `11211`. This should match the parameters you use to run `memcached` from the command line.

EDIT: You can also use XCache not only to store data in a way similar to Memcache, but it will also cache the opcode generated by PHP. This way, instead of reading the PHP code from disk and parsing it each time, it will hold the code in memory for the next request.

Be sure to select `XCache` as the Cache Handler in Global Configuration. Read this for information on installing XCache: http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallFromSource

Answer (score 5):

In order to make Joomla to use memcache for session caching you need to manually edit the configuration.php and change this line:

```
public $session_handler = 'database';
```

to this one:

```
public $session_handler = 'memcache';
```

And this is what is missing everywhere, you need to add a new option memcache_settings:

```
  public $memcache_settings = 'a:3:{s:10:"persistent";s:1:"0";s:11:"compression";s:1:"0";s:7:"servers";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"host";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:4:"port";s:5:"11211";}}}';
```

This is a serialized multy-dimentianal array. I use this code to generate the above string:

```
 $a = array(
   "persistent" => "0", 
   "compression" => "0", 
   "servers" => array(
     "0" => array(
       "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "11211")
     )
   );

echo(serialize($a));
```

If you don't add the memcache_settings option your sessions will never work with memcache.

Answer (score 4):

These settings in `configuration.php` work for `memcached` in Joomla 3.3+

```
public $cache_handler = 'memcached';
public $memcached_server_host = '127.0.0.1';
public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
public $memcached_persist = '1';
public $memcached_compress = '1';
public $cachetime = '15';
public $session_handler = 'memcached';
public $session_memcached_server_host = '127.0.0.1';
public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
```

To install `memcached` on a Debian system:

```
apt-get install memcached php5-memcached
```

(you can also use `memcache` in place of each occurence of `memcached` in the above `public` variables & install the older `php5-memcache` extension)

Upgrading to `php5.5` will give you a builtin [Zend Opcode Cache](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_5_5_s) - this could be used with [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/simplify/INSTALL)  (**APCu** is the [Alternative PHP Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) with the Opcode Cache **removed**) - to cache userland locally if you do not need a distributed memory cache (`memcached`)

For a single VPS [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/simplify/INSTALL) has a lower memory footprint & is a more suitable cache (especially with `php5.5`) & can be set in `configuration.php` with:

```
public $cache_handler = 'apc';
public $session_handler = 'apc';
```

Answer (score 2):

This how to might also offer some help for Joomla 2.5 as it points to the Joomla Admin Screen to use memcache http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/supercacher/joomla_memcached.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's better to **not use** APC for backend cache. This can cause a lot of fragmentation. I have only seen it degrade performance of Joomla.